# MAC, MAMP, 127.0.0.1 connection refused, localhost fine

Tags: macos, apache, server, localhost, mamp

As title says, I can access localhost fine but my app needs a callback from twitter through 127.0.0.1:8000 and 127.0.0.1:8000 is getting "connection refused"

**EDIT**: This looks to be an IPv6 conflict, I can access my local server through (Apache Port) http://127.0.0.1:8888/

**EDITEDIT**: It appears if I serve an angular app on port 9000 I can reach it with `127.0.0.1:9000` in my browser fine, however if I run `php artisan serve --port=9000` then then I still get a connection refused error.

So my issue has been refined to: How can I get `php artisan serve` (for laravel app) to work with http://127.0.0.1:8000/

`Lewiss-MBP:stripe2 Lewis$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/`

The meat:

OSX YOSOMITE 10.10.5

MAMP (non pro) is set to Apache not NGINX

etc/hosts : `file -b /etc/hosts` === ASCII English text

`127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost`

`Lewiss-MBP:applications Lewis$ telnet -6 ::1 8000 </dev/null
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

`Lewiss-MBP:applications Lewis$ telnet -4 127.0.0.1 8000 </dev/null
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: You cannot ping a url or a port. You can only ping a system by its IP or domain name, and that request often is blocked by firewalls. Actually `ping` is not a very good utility to find network issues. Its original purpose is to take a look at network latency. Not more, not less. Take a look instead at utilities like `telnet`, `host`, `dig`, `traceroute`.

Comment: It might be serving over IPv6 only. Try `telnet -6 ::1 8000 </dev/null` and `telnet -4 127.0.0.1 8000 </dev/null`, and see which ones give "Connected to ..." and which give "Connection refused".

Comment: Thanks guys, both great feedback, I've tried Gordon's commands and updated my question. I'll google about IPv6 etc to see if I can resolve this, but if anyone can give me the commands then I'd be very grateful.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. Don't put that into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

l;dr; SOLVED : after a LOT of trawling, if I run `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` my app works fine, as does twitter app callbacks to 127.0.0.1

The issue must be in how Artisan listens..